# PHP MySQL showing other users profiles using the same page as logged in user?

Tags: php, html, profile, member

So currently on my member website, I'm doing things the easy way and using the same page for every users profile, just using the $_SESSION code to bring up different user information depending on the current logged in user.

My question is, how would I bring up other users information? Say if I was searching through the members, clicked a name it should bring up their profile, how could I get that working if I don't have separate pages for each member? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - do you mean to say that in the session variable, is the ID of the logged in user? You use this id to populate that same member file, is this correct?

Comment: Not too sure, I'm using ()session_start to get whatever it is that it uses to check who the logged in user is, then I use $_SESSION(first_name) and all that to bring up their information and display it. But how could I show a users information depending on the name they click ?

Comment: That's the problem there, using the session variables - you're locked in on the whole page. I would have only an ID in session, and pass the id through the URL - this way, on one side you can control where the call comes from: the logged in user, or clicking the href. On the other side, the whole page is dynamic - meaning, it's being filled in through an object "member" that was filled with the ID. Let me know if you follow... not sure I'm expressing myself fully here

Comment: I'm not unfortunately, I'm pretty new when it comes to all of this kind of stuff, which is probably why I'm using the session variable lol! Took me ages just to figure out how to display user information, let alone getting to display other users. I kind of see what you mean in that I'm limited with the way I'm going about it.

Comment: You'll be able to see what I mean if you take a quick look at the site : http://basecentre.co.uk/ the members area is located http://basecentre.co.uk/user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/ because I also haven't figured out how to lock out non logged in users.

Comment: are you using a database, mySql backend?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple.

Let's say, from what you said, you store logged in user ID on $_SESSION and so, you get and use that user ID when you visit the page to fetch the user info from the database, then display it.

Now, here's what I think. Just have a simple IF statement.

```
$uid = (isset($_GET['uid'])) ? $_GET['uid'] : $_SESSION['uid'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $uid";
```

It gets the ID from the URL if it is set, if not, use the id from the session.

```
// this is an example of a URL with uid = 12.
http://yourwebsite.com/profile.php?uid=12
```

So what this does, even if a user is logged in, if s/he visit the page with a `uid = n`, s/he will see someone else's profile.

And so, you have to append/have `uid = n` on every link of your user list.

NOTE: That just a quick and simple example, that code isn't good as is. (i.e. security and validation)

Comment: So where would I have to incorporate that code? Would I add it in to the profile page?

Comment: yes on the profile page, can be right before your database script.

Answer (score -1):

Use a post or get variable of the members ID to display a generic "public" member page for each member, then only display the special "private" features to the user who has a matching Session ID to that member ID. You will have to check the member ID against the session ID each time you are about to echo something "private". When he views other members the ID wont match so he will only see their "public" page and vice versa.